# HTTP Request passing Keywords to search

Tags: java, string, http, httprequest, urlconnection

I made some research to solve my problem but sadly until now I couldn't. It's not such a big deal but I've stuck on it..

I need to make a search with some keywords in search engines such as google. I got two class here to do this:

```
    package com.sh.st;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class EventSearch extends SearchScreen implements ActionListener {

    public EventSearch(){

        btsearch.addActionListener(this);

    }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if(e.getSource()==btsearch){
            String query=txtsearch.getText();
            }

        }



}
```

and

```
    package com.sh.st;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class HttpRequest extends SearchScreen 
{
    URL url = new URL("google.com" + "?" + query).openConnection();
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); //Possible Incompatibility
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

}
```

So, txtsearch comes from another class named SearchScreen and I attributed the value to one string named query. I need to pass query to HttpRequest class and to do this I just extend, I'm sure it's wrong but I saw someone else doing this; and this is the first problem, how may I do this?

the second and most important I'm receiving syntax error:

[image]
[image]

I didn't fully understand the meaning and utility of "connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");"
'course reading I can understand that is regarding the caracters that probably will come up from my request but even though the syntax error is not clear for me

I made research in links such:

1. [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java?lq=1)
2. [getting text from password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162225/getting-text-from-password-field)
3. http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139
4. [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)

All of them have a good material but I can't fully understand everything on it and the part the I'm trying to follow is not working. Could anyone help me please?

Edit: [Topic Solved]

Comment: Please report the syntax error as text

Comment: Fist put your code in some method not in class

Comment: @NullPointerException This those syntax problems, thank you, I'm not so expert in java from now and it's still common for me to do those mistakes. But I'm still missing the part of the string pass between the classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: *(comments inlined)*

```
// Fixed search URL; drop openConnection() at the end
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);

// Setup connection properties (this doesn't open the connection)
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

// Actually, open the HTTP connection
connection.connect();

// Setup a reader
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

// Read line by line
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println (line);
}

// Close connection
reader.close();
```